# How does one keep roto toms in tune?

Tags: drum-kits

Recently, I have been improving the layout of my drumset. One of the additions to my kit so far was a set of roto toms. I've noticed that every time I play on them, the lug nuts tune down slightly. After a while, they are disproportionate to the rest of my drumset. How can I prevent the toms from going out of tune every time I hit them, without tightening them to the point of no return?

Comment: It seems to me that the design of the tuning mechanism will vary from model to model, and this is a question for the customer support of whoever made yours. They should stay in tune.

Comment: What's the brand of your stand? If you can, slide in some cloth between the shaft and the locking nut to create more friction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tuning guide that showed up in a search: http://vintagedrumguide.com/images/my_collection/literature/remo/roto3.jpg

Make sure that you are staying within the practical range, depending on the size of the roto tom.  If you're tuning higher, in the extended range, it may be more difficult to keep it in tune.

Also, have you changed the heads at all?  Might want to verify the integrity of the heads.